# Absolutely positioned links shifting to unexpected position on click (a:active)

Tags: css, css-position

I have a couple links on this page (http://tuscaroratackle.com) that are ending up at unexpected positions in their :active state. The links are absolutely positioned, so I'm guessing the issue is partly due to that. But I can't figure out what rules are getting applied on :active to make them shift down and to the left so far. I do have one rule that makes them "depress" a bit on active ( `a:active {position:relative; top:1px;}` ) but can't quite figure out why they are shifting so badly.

The links in question are these:

[image: tusc-tkl-bug]

it's the "See Rods" link that appears on hover. If you click you'll see the awkward resulting positioning.

*Also for those that don't know (I recently found out) you can inspect the :active state in firefug. Just use the drop down arrow on the style tab to toggle those styles on.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From description of `position:absolute`:
*Generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.*

And, as you noted, you have `position:relative;` defined for `a:active`. Now, therefore, in `<a><span></span></a>` combination position of `span` is counted relative to position of `a`, not to position of `.hp-promo-item`.

As for solution, if you need to move `a` down 1 pixel on `:active`, maybe `margin-top` will work better. But wait, you already have `margin-top:1px` for `.promo-content .icon`. Well, maybe `margin-top:2px !important;` then. I don't really understand the aim to suggest more.

PS Thanks for telling about `:active` helper in firebug, pretty useful!

Comment: FYI - your answer helped me resolve the issue simply by making me realize I needed to add "position:relative" to the containing div, so that my absolute positioning was consistent on both :hover, and :active. All works as expected now. Thanks!!